# Set up Maven in Intellij with TestNG using POM to read .xml suite

Tags: maven

Hey I have my project set up with Maven structure:
My pom file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.QASelenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyTemp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
         <!--   <scope>test</scope>     -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
         <!--   <scope>test</scope>   -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My TestNGTest.java file is under src/main/resources:

```java
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class TestNGTest{

    @Test
    @Parameters(value="number")
    public void parameterIntTest(int number) {
        System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + number);
    }
}
```

When I compile it with TestNG using IntelliJ, WHy I always get this error:

**org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'number' is required by @Test on method parameterIntTest but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users(My_Name).IdeaIC12\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml**

Can someone please point to me where I got it running wrong?
I am new to the maven, Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all is fine, but if you are using xml suite, then you need to execute test from suite, not from class.

```
Run/Debug Configurations
Configuration -> Suite
Suite: /PATH/PROJECT/src/test/resources/testng.xml
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, MariuszS. But I still not understand, do you mean I need to change my pom file? or my testing.xml? In testing.xml file, change <class/> to <suite/>, how? can you be more specific, sorry, I am new to using maven. Thanks.

Comment: I figure it out. As you pointed out, I need to execute the test from the suite: testing.xml. not from the .java file itself. Thanks so much.